# How to match value from other table before entering new record?

Tags: php, mysql

Count record before entering into table - and match it with other table value.

Currently, I am working to make an online quiz, I am able to add new questions but want to count existing questions count (against `testid`) and match it from another table where the total number of questions are added.

Like I have a table named as `testname` where `testid`, title, and `totalquestion` are added.

Next table is of `mst_question` where against `testid` record are entered.

```
if($_POST[submit]=='Save' || strlen($_POST['testid'])>0 )
{
extract($_POST);
mysql_query("insert into 
mst_question(test_id,que_desc,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans) values 
('$testid','$addque','$ans1','$ans2','$ans3','$ans4','$anstrue')",$cn) or 
die(mysql_error());
echo "Question Added Successfully!";
unset($_POST);
}
```

Comment: mysql_query shouldn't be use anymore since almost 10 years (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: What's this? `$_POST[submit]`

Comment: This is brilliant, I've never ever seen `unset($_POST);` untill now

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Please stop using php5 and even php7.0 is outdated version. use php 7.3 for new projects

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand why you store "totalquestion" in your table? If you want to know the current total number of questions, just `COUNT()` them. Unless I have not understood the purpose of that field, you don't need to store a running total of the questions. Instead, just calculate how many there are, as and when you need to.